# How to set one content type to only one language in a multilingual site?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a multi language website, it's for both English and Arabic, the site's default language is English, but for specific content type which is blog section of the website. I need to set it's default language to Arabic and to never translate it's content. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module then go to edit your content type and under ***Publishing options*** in ***Multilingual support*** check the option  ***Enabled, with field translation***

[image]

Go to: YOUR_SITE/admin/config/regional/entity_translation and configure your content type like this:

[image]

Obviously I select French but in your case you must select Arabic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian for your answer, i tested it and it works fine :)

You saved me twice today, this problem and the multi language support for fivestar module :) Thanks a lot (Y)

Comment: @silver157 a pleasure help you, and god luck with your project ;-)

Comment: @silver157 I saw at drupal.org that my patch to fivestar works for you :-) I don't know why it don't pass the automated test, can you make one review to the patch?

Comment: Forgive me Adrian as i'm not an expert in Drupal, i applied this patch manually but i found that there is a problem with lines numbers, may this was the problem.

Comment: @silver157 thanks, maybe this is the problem, really you help me with this, I will review the patch again ;-)

Comment: I'm pleased for being able to help, you helped me a lot of times :)

Comment: @silver157 I reviewed the fivestar patch again, now it's works fine: see this https://www.drupal.org/node/1834256#comment-10820534 as you test the patch, can you change the status to "reviewed and tested by the community"?